# Complex Analysis Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am not sure how to solve the following problem:

Use Liouville's theorem to prove that if f(z) is holomorhpic in the in entire complex plane and $f(z+1) = f(z)$, and $f(z+i)=f(z)$ for all $z$ in $C$ then $f$ is constant.

I have never done a Liouville's theorem question before - is there a general method to doing these types of questions?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to provide a reference to Liouville's theorem to make it easier for someone wanting to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:Show that $f$ is bounded, using the two periods $1$ and $i$.